# Reliably getting favicons in Chrome extensions, chrome://favicon?

Tags: permissions, google-chrome-extension, favicon

I'm using the `chrome://favicon/` in my [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp) to get the favicon for RSS feeds. What I do is get the base path of linked page, and append it to `chrome://favicon/http://<domainpath>`.

It's working really unreliably. A lot of the time it's reporting the standard "no-favicon"-icon, even when the page really has a favicon. There is almost 0 documentation regarding the `chrome://favicon` mechanism, so it's difficult to understand how it actually works. Is it just a cache of links that have been visited? Is it possible to detect if there was an icon or not?

From some simple testing it's just a cache of favicons for pages you have visited. So if I subscribe to dribbble.com's RSS feed, it won't show a favicon in my extension. Then if I visit `chrome://favicon/http://dribbble.com/` it won't return right icon. Then I open dribbble.com in another tab, it shows its icon in the tab, then when I reload the `chrome://favicon/http://dribbble.com/`-tab, it will return the correct favicon. Then I open my extensions popup and it still shows the standard icon. But if I then restart Chrome it will get the correct icon everywhere.

Now that's just from some basic research, and doesn't get me any closer to a solution. So my question is: Is the `chrome://favicon/` a correct use-case for what I'm doing. Is there any documentation for it? And what is this its intended behavior?

Comment: I know that it's been a while since you asked it. Can you share how you were able to get the favicon for a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now the official documentation for [Favicon Permission - Fetching favicons](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/favicon/).

## Add `favicon` to your permission

```json
{
  "name": "Favicon API in a popup",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  ...
  "permissions": ["favicon"],
  ...
}
```

## Access the favicon URL

For my simple case:

```js
const favIconUrl = `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/_favicon/?pageUrl=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&size=32`;
```

From their example:

```js
function faviconURL(u) {
  const url = new URL(chrome.runtime.getURL("/_favicon/"));
  url.searchParams.set("pageUrl", u);
  url.searchParams.set("size", "32");
  return url.toString();
}

const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = faviconURL("https://www.google.com") 
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

This also works on Chromium Edge, it automatically transform `chrome-extension://`
into `extension://`

**Note:** when fetching favicons in content scripts, the "_favicon/*" folder must be declared as a web accessible resource. For example:

```json
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["_favicon/*"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "extension_ids": ["*"]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 24):

I've seen this problem as well and it's really obnoxious.

From what I can tell, Chrome populates the chrome://favicon/ cache after you visit a URL (omitting the #hash part of the URL if any). It appears to usually populate this cache sometime *after* a page is completely loaded. If you try to access chrome://favicon/http://yoururl.com before the associated page is completely loaded you will often get back the default 'globe icon'. Subsequently refreshing the page you're displaying the icon(s) on will then fix them.

So, if you can, possibly just refreshing the page you're displaying the icons on just prior to displaying it to the user may serve as a fix.

In my use case, I am actually opening tabs which I want to obtain the favicons from. So far the most reliable approach I have found to obtain them looks roughly like this:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(onCompleted);

function onCompleted(details)
{
    if (details.frameId > 0)
    {
        // we don't care about activity occurring within a subframe of a tab
        return;
    }

    chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function(tab) {
        var url = tab.url ? tab.url.replace(/#.*$/, '') : ''; // drop #hash
        var favicon;
        var delay;

        if (tab.favIconUrl && tab.favIconUrl != '' 
            && tab.favIconUrl.indexOf('chrome://favicon/') == -1) {
            // favicon appears to be a normal url
            favicon = tab.favIconUrl;
            delay = 0;
        }
        else {
            // couldn't obtain favicon as a normal url, try chrome://favicon/url
            favicon = 'chrome://favicon/' + url;
            delay = 100; // larger values will probably be more reliable
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            /// set favicon wherever it needs to be set here
            console.log('delay', delay, 'tabId', tab.id, 'favicon', favicon);
        }, delay);
    });
}
```

This approach returns the correct favicon about 95% of the time for new URLs, using delay=100. Increasing the delay if you can accept it will increase the reliability (I'm using 1500ms for my use case and it misses <1% of the time on new URLs; this reliability worsens when many tabs are being opened simultaneously). Obviously this is a pretty imprecise way of making it work but it is the best method I've figured out so far.

Another possible approach is to instead pull favicons from http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=somedomain.com. I don't like this approach very much as it requires accessing the external network, relies on a service that has no guarantee of being up, and is itself somewhat unreliable; I have seen it inconsistently return the "globe" icon for a www.domain.com URL yet return the proper icon for just domain.com.

Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: I did not know about the faviconURL property of tab! Unfortunately, I want something that works retroactively, without opening the page in tab. But this was helpful, and I do believe I can add this now, for future users. I just wish that it wasn't so complicated.

Comment: I've submitted a Chrome defect report in hopes of getting this problem addressed: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131018

Comment: I tried this code and can't get it to work. When I call chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(onCompleted); I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCompleted' of undefined. I do have the permission "webNavigation" set in the manifest. Any idea why chrome.webNavigation seems to be undefined?

Comment: Not really sure why that would be happening... are you using manifest.json v2? Not using the v2 style was breaking my extension for a while recently. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html

Answer (score 7):

[As of Oct 2020](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/857c4ddd59fd29ed2ff02d67e55ec72008831298), it appears chrome extensions using manifest version 3 are no longer able to access `chrome://favicon/*` urls. I haven't found the 'dedicated API' the message refers to.

> Manifest v3 and higher extensions will not have access to the
> chrome://favicon host; instead, we'll provide a dedicated API
> permission and different URL. This results in being able to
> tighten our permissions around the chrome:-scheme.

Comment: Some insight on the Chromium bug tracker: [Issue 104102: Create a new API permission for access to favicons](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104102)

Comment: It seems like the best solution currently(for MV3) is to use the Google Favicon Snatcher: https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.google.com

Comment: The problem with these is that, you cant implement this unless you want to lose your user base

Comment: New API example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73415941/766850

Answer (score 6):

In order to use chrome://favicon/some-site in extension. manifest.json  need to be updated:

```
"permissions": ["chrome://favicon/"],
"content_security_policy": "img-src chrome://favicon;"
```

Test on Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Thanks for this. Here's relevant Chromium changes to allow extensions to access favicons: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37802

Answer (score 6):

`chrome://favicon` url is deprecated in favor of new favicon API with manifest v3.

```json
// manifest.json
{
  "permissions": ["favicon"]
}
```

```js
// utils.js
function getFaviconUrl(url) {
  return `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/_favicon/?pageUrl=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&size=32`;
}
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/qS1rVpQVl8o/m/qmg1M13wBAAJ

Answer (score 4):

I inspected the website-icon in Chrome history page and found this simpler method. 
You can get the favicon url by  --

```
favIconURL = "chrome://favicon/size/16@1x/" + tab.url;
```

Don't forget to add "permissions" and "content_security_policy" to Chrome. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48304708/9586876)

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of Chrome, `Version 78.0.3904.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)`) when tested, adding just `img-src chrome://favicon;` as `content_security_policy` will still show 2 warnings:

> `'content_security_policy'`: CSP directive `'script-src'` must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via `'default-src'`) and must whitelist only secure resources.

And:

> `'content_security_policy'`: CSP directive `'object-src'` must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via `'default-src'`) and must whitelist only secure resources.

To get rid of them use:

```
"permissions": ["chrome://favicon/"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; img-src chrome://favicon;"
```

Now you can use `chrome://favicon/http://example.com` without getting any errors or warnings.

Comment: I tried this solution but with no luck. When my content script tries to show some a tab's favicon it gets  `Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://favicon/https://www.google.com`. Tested on Chrome 88.0.4324.146