# Displaying chrome://favicon/ on newtab page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a **Google Chrome extension** where bookmarks are displayed on the **newtab** page. Everything works fine so far except for the favicons.

Entering this URL in Chrome displays the favicon of a page:

> chrome://favicon/https://stackoverflow.com/

However, in the **newtab**, which I properly set up, they don't get displayed.

The HTML is very simple, though:

```
<img src="chrome://favicon/https://stackoverflow.com/" />
```

Comment: I think it needs a permission.. Do you have a `"chrome://favicon/"` permission?

Comment: Wow, must have missed that. Post it in the answers & I'll give you a +1 & accept :)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm pretty convinced the new tab page does not display a favicon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's anywhere in the docs, but accessing `chrome://favicon/` needs a special permission `"chrome://favicon/"` in the manifest.

Do note:

- This [may change](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104102) in the future.
- `chrome://favicon` is [not entirely reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10665321/934239).

Comment: That's why I missed it. An undocumented feature. I'll monitor that and when it changes, I'll change my code. Thanks!