# Can a chrome extension load an image from "chrome-search://ntpicon"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

`chrome-search://ntpicon/size/24@2x/https://news.ycombinator.com/`

The default google startpage uses this URL format to load icons for `topSites`. When I try to load this URL in my extension, I get the error:

`Not allowed to load local resource: chrome-search://ntpicon/size/24@2x/https://news.ycombinator.com/`

Is there any permission I can give my extension to be able to load these URLs?

Comment: Extensions [can load icons from chrome://favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140923/displaying-chrome-favicon-on-newtab-page), including hidpi [modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33349965).