# How to get the favicon of websites for making chrome extensions?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, favicon

I am trying to create a chrome extension that overrides the newtab page with a speed dial but I not able to give the websites their favicon in the speed dial. Is there a chrome API or another way to get the favicon of the websites?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56856376).

Comment: Have you ever used Safari? Do they use favicon for tiles of websites in the start page?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Manifest V3 has a new API for fetching website favicons.

To show favicon image in a new tab page, you will need to do two things:

1. Declare **favicon** permission in manifest.json
2. Create image URL using special protocol: **chrome-extension://{your_extension_id}/_favicon/?pageUrl={website_url}&size=16**

Here is a developer focused article discussing [new extension favicon API](https://www.extension.ninja/blog/post/new-chrome-extension-mv3-favicon-fetch-api/) usage and more practical scenarios. And the link to [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/favicon/).