# Why do Firefox and Chrome return different results for tabs.Tab.favIconUrl? And how can I work around this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

#### The problem

I am writing a WebExtension that makes use of the tab's favicon. I retrieve the URL of the current tab's favicon in this way:

```js
var API = chrome || browser;
API.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    if (tabs[0] && tabs[0].favIconUrl) {
        console.log(tabs[0].favIconUrl);
    }
});
```

In Firefox, the console logs an `image/x-icon` data URI representing the image data, but in Chrome, the console logs a plain URL that points to the icon's location. For example, if I run this in `stackoverflow.com` on Firefox, I get:

```
data:image/x-icon;base64,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
```

but in Chrome, I get:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196
```

#### Why this is a problem

I need the data URI because I want to draw the favicon on my own canvas:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = tabs[0].favIconUrl;
img.decode()
    .then(() => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, size, size);
        // do other stuff on ctx ...
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This does not work in Chrome because the favicon URL points to a different domain, so I run into this error:
`Access to image at 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196' from origin 'https://stackoverflow.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

and the image decode errors with `DOMException: The source image cannot be decoded.`

#### How do I work around this?

Both [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab) and [Google](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) list the same description for `Tab.favIconUrl` and there is no mention of this difference in behavior [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities#JavaScript_APIs). How else can I retrieve the active tab's favicon Data URI in a cross-browser compatible way?

Comment: Look at the actual DOM to see the actual url, it's probably different. You'll have to add `*://*/` to `permissions` in order to solve the Canvas problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome you can use the favicon cache url `chrome://favicon/https://google.com` instead of relying on the Tabs API. See this for examples:

[Reliably getting favicons in Chrome extensions, chrome://favicon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665321/reliably-getting-favicons-in-chrome-extensions-chrome-favicon)