# Extracted favicon using "chrome://favicon/size/16@3x/" doesn't load the favicon

Tags: java, html, favicon

I am trying to load the favicon of a different website using chrome favicon API `chrome://favicon/size/16@3x/` when loading the page it shows a broken Icon.

Example code:

```
<img class="img-favicon" alt="icon" src="chrome://favicon/size/16@3x/https://replit.com/~"
```

Am I missing something what is it that I am doing wrong here? Any help, please.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my research, you cannot use the chrome favicon API outside of extensions/chrome itself.

If you are building a chrome extension, then you would have to add some custom permissions to the manifest.json described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48304708

If you were looking to grab favicons in a regular website, there exists some websites that offer APIs etc which you can use to get the favicon link, such as this: https://favicongrabber.com/service-api-reference

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I am not building an extension, I will look for a different solution.